# How to parse JSON in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin

How can I parse JSON in Kotlin?  It gets the entire array from JSON but can not get a particular object from the Array.

It worked in Java but not in Kotlin.

```
try {
    val jsonObject = JSONObject(result)
    val users = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Users")
    for (i in 0 until users.length())
    {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Json Result is----"+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val obj = users.getJSONObject(i)
        val name = obj.get("name").toString()
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "User name: "+name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}catch(e: JSONException){}
```

Comment: Show your `json` data .

Comment: If it works in Java, why use Kotlin? Please format your code, it looks pretty awful.

Comment: Also, if it works in Java you can get an idea of how Kotlin code should be by letting IntelliJ convert Java to Kotlin (`Code -> Convert Java file to Kotlin file`). The result might not be perfect, but it's a good starting point

Comment: post your json url or data

Comment: This is my Json array: I need particular json object( such as name)

{
 "Users": [{
   "id": "U1",
   "name": "John",
   "age": "20",
   "gender": "male",
   "email": {
    "primary": "john@gmail.com",
    "secondary": "many@gmail.com"
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "U2",
   "name": "Sam",
   "age": "28",
   "gender": "male",
   "email": {
    "primary": "sam@gmail.com",
    "secondary": "kid@gmail.com"
   }
  }

 ]
}

Comment: just use [Gson ](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: Use Moshi - gson 3.0 https://github.com/square/moshi

Answer (score 0):

Use `jsonObject.getString(paramName: String)`, not `jsonObject.get(paramName: String).toString()`.

Or you can also cast this object to string.
See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

The best and quick practice is instead of manually checking for each key, generate native Kotlin "data classes" using tools e.g. https://json2kotlin.com

So your API response turns into the following couple of data classes corresponding to the JSON structure:

```
data class Json4Kotlin_Base (

    val users : List<Users>
)
```

and

```
data class Users (

    val id : String,
    val name : String,
    val age : Int,
    val gender : String,
    val email : Email
)
```

and

```
data class Email (

    val primary : String,
    val secondary : String
)
```

When you get the result, you simple map the JSON response to these data classes. The [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n46WbgNoEnE) shows how to do it step by step, and includes more sample code.